# A question about unreachable stopping time

Tags: statistics, stopping-times

I have two questions related to the stopping time.

Suppose we have a iid sequence $X_n$, where $P(X<0)=1$. And we have a stopping time N, N=$\inf${n:$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i>0$}.

======================================================

My First question is what the value of E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$) is.

For one side, because we set the stopping rule such that $\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ has to be greater than $0$, so E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$) should be greater than 0.

On the other hand, because $X_i$ is always less than $0$, and the stopping rule will never be satisfied, so N=$\infty$, and therefore E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$)=-$\infty$.

======================================================

Me second question is actually related to the first question: What is E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$|N)? Is that $0$ or a positive number or negative infinity?

Because if it is $0$, We can use the expectation of the conditional expectation to solve E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$), so E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$) =$E_N$($E_X$($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$|N))=$E_N(0)$=$0$.

If it is a positive number, we can use the same technique to solve E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$) and find E($\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$)$>0$.

From different aspect one can end up with different result, but there must be only one result. Could any one see the problem for the above solutions? I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Here you should write $$N=\inf\left\{n>0: \sum_{i=1}^n X_i >0\right\} $$ as that implicitly means we are taking the convention $$\left\{N=\infty\right\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\leqslant 0\right\}. $$

Comment: You are right, I've changed that. But I still cannot understand my question. Could you make it more clear? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb P(X_1<0)=1$, it is clear that $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i < 0\right\} \right) = 1. $$ This implies that $\mathbb P(N=\infty)=1$, and so by monotone convergence (applied to $-X_n$) $$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right] = \mathbb E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i \right] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb E[X_i] = -\infty. $$
(This is assuming $\mathbb E[X_1]>-\infty$ - else the sum is clearly $-\infty$.)

Since $\mathbb P(N=\infty)=1$, we have $\sigma(N) = \{\varnothing, \Omega\}$ - so conditioning on $N$ does not change anything, and $$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\mid N\right] = \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right] =-\infty.$$